# How to get data from json with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

i've response from ajax here is json

`{"status":"OK"}`

then im trying to get status value

```
var send = $('#button'),
numer = $('#number');
send.on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (form.valid()) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/file.php",
        data: { number: number.val() },
        success: function(data) {
            var test = data + '';
            var objData;
            var status;
            try {
                objData = $.parseJSON(test);
                status = objData['status'];
                if (objData['status'] != 'OK') {
                    console.log(status);
                    form.attr('validated', true);
                    form.unbind().submit();
                    response = false;

                } else {
                    console.log(status);
                    response = true;
                }

            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
return false;
});
```

then when im trying to get value im geting undefinied, where is the problem, can anyone help me to find proper salutoion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this work but try to insert this code `dataType: "json",` after `url: "/file.php",` and change `objData['status']` with `data.status`

UPDATE 
this is a simple code iv tried

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
     //alert("OK");
     jsonData = {"status":"OK"};

     if (jsonData.status != 'OK') {
        alert("STATUS NOT OK");
     } else {
        alert("STATUS OK");
     }

    });
```

Comment: undefined its drive me crazy cos one second server is working fine

Comment: maybe your Json data return empty value. i have update for simple code when jsondata status is OK. sory my English poor

Comment: to its not this is really strange cos its not working on one server

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `data.status` within your `success` handler. You don't need to call `$.parseJSON()` on the `data` as jQuery already deserialises it for you. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.status != 'OK') {
        form.attr('validated', true).unbind().submit();
    } else {
        // handle the other status values here...
    }
}
```

Also note that your logic appears backwards - are you sure you want to set the form to 'validated' and submit it when the response is *not* `OK`?

Comment: but when i console console.log(data.status) i've undefined

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: "{\"status\":\"OK\"}" this when i console log data exactly like that

Comment: You're returning a string. Use `json_encode()` in your PHP file.

Comment: yes echo json_encode(file_get_contents($url)); its look like that